# Grant Read access to a single file with Google Drive API for server-side apps

Tags: javascript, java, google-api, google-oauth

I have implemented a web application where the client prompts the user to authorize the backend to read a specific Google spreadsheet using the Google APIs.

I noticed that all of the predefined access scopes give access to all of the files associated with the user's account not to a single file, except for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file. However, this would not work in my case as the file will not be opened or created by the app but it will be downloaded by the backend server. Is it possible to grant Read access to a single Google sheet with the Google Drive API?